# Why is Spotify playing out of my laptop speakers? Sound is set to HDMI and browser is successfully playing through HDMI

Tags: gnome, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

So to start, I'm not too great at ubuntu and this particular laptop is probably a bit of a mess because it's where I first tried any distro of linux and I haven't really cleaned it up or anything. I say this because it's possible I'm just missing some pulse or alsa software addon or I might have not configured something right.

I just got the computer running again after it had some issues for a long time and I've been hooking it up to my tv through HDMI

The issue is, I have opened my sound settings and set the output to HDMI and it's... not working... all the way?

Most things are only playing out of the built-in laptop speakers, which are absolute crap. The sound settings "test" won't make any noise. Spotify will only play through the built-in speakers. However... the browser will play through HDMI as intended.

What is causing these applications to play out of different speakers and how do I begin to start fixing it?

This may be relevant: For some reason, when I use the TV as a second monitor or mirror, and set the display to 200% so that the text is big enough to see on a 4k TV, Spotify is proportionate with everything else. With it set to "one display" and using the TV, Spotify is not proportionate and sizes itself based on the TV's native resolution (so it's tiny and you can see everything at once, which is kind of interesting, but also hard to read)

I mention this because I wonder if Spotify is grabbing for native settings or something and bypassing my own settings? Idk, I'm at a loss and just hoping for some help from someone who knows a lot more than me

Edit: sorry, I thought I said but guess I forgot to say I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, GNOME 3.36.8 on a laptop

Comment: @guiverc edited

Comment: If you installed the snap package, I think you need to enable permissions by right clicking on the launcher icon and adjusting the settings. If that doesn't work, I would file a bug. However, not sure how bugs are filed for snap packages but you can ask a question about that if you can't find the answer.